# How to add another keyboard on click key code

Tags: android

I have to add a new character keyboard, current one is alphanumeric. It would be great if I get help on switching between keyboards. I have my keyboard ready but only the switch part is remaining.

**Here is the main code below.**

```
public class SimpleIME extends InputMethodService implements OnKeyboardActionListener {

  private KeyboardView kv;
  private Keyboard keyboard;

  private boolean caps = false;

  @Override
  public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
    InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
    playClick(primaryCode);
    switch(primaryCode){
        case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE :
            ic.deleteSurroundingText(1, 0);
            break;
        case Keyboard.KEYCODE_SHIFT:
            caps = !caps;
            keyboard.setShifted(caps);
            kv.invalidateAllKeys();
            break;
        case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DONE:
            ic.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER));
            break;
        default:
            char code = (char)primaryCode;
            if(Character.isLetter(code) && caps){
                code = Character.toUpperCase(code);
            }
            ic.commitText(String.valueOf(code),1);
      }
  }

  @Override
  public void onPress(int primaryCode) {
  }

  @Override
  public void onRelease(int primaryCode) {
  }

  @Override
  public void onText(CharSequence text) {
  }

  @Override
  public void swipeDown() {
  }

  @Override
  public void swipeLeft() {
  }

  @Override
  public void swipeRight() {
  }

  @Override
  public void swipeUp() {
  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateInputView() {
    kv = (KeyboardView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.keyboard, null);
    keyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.qwerty);
    kv.setKeyboard(keyboard);
    kv.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
    return kv;
  }

  private void playClick(int keyCode) {
    AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
    switch (keyCode) {
        case 32:
            am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_SPACEBAR);
            break;
        case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DONE:
        case 10:
            am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_RETURN);
            break;
        case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE:
            am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_DELETE);
            break;
        default:
            am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_STANDARD);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was asked a year ago, but I'll give you the answer because it might help other people.

Underneath the following code: 
"case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DONE:
     ic.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,      KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER));
            break;"

Put this code:
"case -201:
     keyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.symbols);
     kv.setKeyboard(keyboard);
     break;"

Then go to your qwerty.xml file and assign a button the code '-201'. When this button is pushed by the user, the keyboard view will switch to show 'symbols.xml'